# Jobscheduler after application removed from recent apps

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-jobscheduler

I have jobscheduler that sends notification  trigged by starting alarm and get canceled by an ending alarm, I have question, if i remove application from recent app or i reboot phone will alarm will trigged on specified time? and what happens to job scheduler

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be triggered. Alarm manager are system based not app base as long as you have that app installed in your device (and obviously alarm is set) alarm will be triggered on that specific time.

Comment: What about other post saying that you have to reset alarms after reboot by having broadcast receiver ONBOOTCOMPLETED?

Comment: and what about job scheduler

Comment: I have tested that. You can also do the same. Create some alarms. and wait for trigger. And restart your cell phone and boom. Alarms will be triggered.

Comment: what about job scheduler, if i reboot or remove application from recent will scheduler maintained?

Comment: No, it persists across reboots - which is considered as an improvement.